# Is `this.props` possible to be changed in the component itself?

Tags: reactjs, react-class-based-component

As the title says, is `this.props` possible to be changed in the component itself whether manually or automatically

manual change example

```js
this.props.someData = 'some value'
```

I don't know how to change `this.props` automatically, so I can't write example of automatical change.

Comment: No you shouldn't change the props inside the component. Instead, include a callback method in the props from the parent component.

Comment: Why do you want to change the props?

Comment: @mousetail I don't want to change the props inside the component itself. But the props keeps changing and I don't know why and where. So I asked that question.

Comment: @Thomas I don't want to change, But the props keep changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @mousetail suggested, it's best practise to add an updater callback to the props:

`this.props.updateData(value);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to know if the props can be changed whether manually or automatically inside the component itself.

Comment: Sorry, I understand. Props are immutable, so you can't. Can we help you find the source of the flaky prop?

Comment: Sorry, I can't show any source code. That is our company product. I still exactly don't know why `this.props` was changing, but I solved my problem. Thank you for speding time for me.

Comment: Great!
(You could always share a stripped down version of the code, just to showcase the situation)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that `this.props` automatically changed when a function was executed.

In code level, there is no code to change `this.props`.

And problem was solved suddenly when I turned on the `redux-devtools`.

I'm guessing there's a problem somewhere inside the library, but I'm not sure.

If someone knows about this problem or similar problem, please let me know.

And I'm very thankful to all the people that tried to help me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).